# Saving $("#some-id") in a variable to access it later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save selected jQuery object to some variable and to be able to access it after navigating to some other page, since after reloading it disappears.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var active_accordion;

$(function() {
    active_accordion.prop('checked', true);
    $('.active-evm a').on('click', function() {
        active_accordion = $('#section-1');
        alert(active_accordion);
    });
}
```

Whenever link is clicked I save `$('#section-1')` to `active_accordion`, and after navigating to other page I try to change property `checked` to `true`.

Of course it doesn't work, because `active_accordion` disappears after navigation. So where can I store it?

Comment: store it in session state, just look at this link http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557 it will help you

Comment: You could store it in the browsers local storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: But if store jquery selector in localstorage and reload the page, then the dom element stored in localstorage will be changed. It'll not reffer the element in the dom after reload.

Answer (score 1):

save to local storage,

the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp),

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in session storage `sessionStorage`.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("itemKey", value);
```

Edit: `sessionStorage` items persist as long as the browser session is active.
If you want to persist your items even if you restart your browser, you can use `localStorage`, but be careful with its usage as the data tends to get stale if you do not use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways you can do this

1) Store those in `session`

2) Store it on `cookies`

> Note :when using Cookies be careful, don't put too much in them (I
>   think there is a limit at 4kb).

3) you can store it in local storage in your system 
example : save values to a file

4) you can store it on database

5) Or just use [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557)

> PersistJS is good choice  because you can store large objects like
>   window objects aswell

6) You can use the help of [WebStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

7)you can use `window.name`

it is  originated  before localStorage/sessionStorage, you can  store information in the window.name property:

```
window.name = "stringvalue"
```

> It can only store strings

, so if you want to save an object you'll have to stringify it just like the above localStorage example:

```
window.name = JSON.stringify({ object });
```